# Include A View Of Another Controller Within Views/site/index

Tags: php, templates, yii

I can't figure out how to solve this problem i'm facing. Alright, so basically i have a default view/site/index.php view file which is generating the home page. Now i have built two separated Models and their associated Controllers and views. I want to include those view of the controllers in the default home page view i.e. views/site/index.php. Does it make any sense ?

So my home page is divided into several sections. The header and footer parts are the same throughout the whole site, which is why i've written them in the /themes/brushed/layouts folder under separate files. Those are being loaded fine.

The two controller i was talking about are named as FrontPageCategoriesController.php and TopProductsController.php. They are generating their separate view files i.e. index.php in their respective view folders.

How will i include those view files (index.php) into the main site view file (views/site/index.php). I just can't include those files using include_once() because the data is being generated yet by its controller. So whats the way to achieve this ?

Can anyone please help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should move data generation from controller to model. Controller should only wire your input parameters to model and pass it to view. The reason is that you want to reuse models, not controllers. Remember that controller is bound to page request, while model is not.

Then just use your model to fetch the data and `renderPartial` to render the data. For example:

```
$categories = FrontPageCategories::model()->findAll();
$this->renderPartial('/frontPageCategories/index', array(
    'categories' => $categories,
));
```

In fact it is possible to fetch categories from model directly in view, if they are not dependant on some parameters in the current page.

Actually, you should use `renderPartial` for your header and footer too.

Comment: Yes that works. Ok, i understand it. The thing is a lot of tutorials says that business logic should be kept in Controller and the Models should only interface with the databases. So i thought that in order to use the view of another controller i need to include that controller in the present one somehow. It didn't occured to me that Models could be used like that. I thought that they were bound to Controller and has no separate existence.

Comment: Anyways, thanks a lot for this. I'm really grateful for this.

Comment: Also one more thing. So a Model class has almost a global scope, right ?

Comment: I mean i can use it almost anywhere ? In any views and in any controllers?

Comment: With active record that Yii (and also Ruby on Rails) uses there seems to be some confusion what part of your model is business logic and what is database interface, because those two things are often mixed together.

Comment: In any case business logic should never be part of controller (any tutorial claiming this is wrong). In Yii you may inherit CModel for your business logic and CActiveRecord for database access if you want to separate business logic and database interface, but for simple cases (and simple is relative here, because CActiveRecord lets you do quite complicated things) this is not necessary.

Comment: And when it comes to using models, you can use it almost anywhere, in controller, view, or in console application. If you cannot use your model in console application, for example, you are doing something wrong. Model is sort of API for your app, it shouldn't matter where you use it. On more thing, you can use your model in your view, but your view should not do any business logic. It is not ok to call something like Article::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('pinned' => 1)), but it's ok to call Article::model()->pinned().

Comment: Last comment :) You may check http://matthewpaulmoore.com/post/5190436725/ruby-on-rails-code-quality-checklist - it's for Ruby on Rails, but because Yii also uses active record, it can be applied here too.

Comment: What a great advice ! It simply didn't occured to me that CModel can be inherited for business logic. And i've read that Behaviors can also be attached to models, which allows to implement even more logic in the model. And yes i always do just the presentation in my views, that way its neat and managable.

Comment: Anyways thanks for that link and the wonderful tips. I really appreciate it.